# PHP Double Quotes from MySQL, breaking htmlentities

Tags: php, quotes

I am having an issue with my results here.
Please someone can tell what I'm doing wrong.

I have this text inside a mysql field:

```
----------------------------------------------------
text “strange double quotes” "normal double quotes"
----------------------------------------------------
```

Inside a textarea I echo the string fron the database

```
<textarea>
    $string = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($string,ENT_QUOTES));
    echo htmlspecialchars($string);
</textarea>
```

And crashes (does not display anything).

---

but if I only have normal text or normal quotes:

```
"this is a correct text with quotes"
```

This works.

Do you know what I need to do?

TY

Comment: What is the purpose of `stripslashes` and `htmlspecialchars_decode` here? To make data safe, all you need is the `htmlspecialchars` (although it is a good idea to specify the character set in that call).

Comment: What is the nature of the crash you are experiencing? What error do you get, or what makes you believe it is a crash?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have works as expected:

```
<?php
$string = 'text “strange double quotes” "normal double quotes"';

$string = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($string,ENT_QUOTES));
echo htmlspecialchars($string);
?>
```

Yields:

```
text “strange double quotes” &quot;normal double quotes&quot;
```

Check the value of `$string` before passing it into `htmlspecialchars_decode`, e.g.:

```
<?php
$string = null;

$string = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($string,ENT_QUOTES));
echo htmlspecialchars($string);
?>
```

Yields nothing/empty/blank, per your error description.

Comment: that same piece of code, tested alone in a test.php file I just created. does not work in my machine. Wamp php 5.5.12.

http://clip2net.com/s/j1B5ag

Comment: @JoseFaro I'm 5.5.9 x86 vc11 thread safe on xampp on windows. Is it bombing on `htmlspecialchars_decode`, `stripslashes`, or `htmlspecialchars`? Need some `var_dumps`'s to really see what's going on for your specific case. Update your question with incremental debug output.